# how to retrieve an array of dates with find condition in rails2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to make a query from a Student table. But in the students table it has only one date column(joining_date). I need to get all the students who has joined from beginning of that month to end of that month...
I am getting as params @start_date = "2013-09-01"

I tried like the below.. But didn't work.

```
Student.find(:all, :conditions => ["joining_date=? and joined=?",@start_date.beginning_of_month..@start_date.end_of_month,true])
```

So is there any way to do this.. Or is it better to query via named_scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
named_scope :joined,   lambda { { :conditions => { :joined => true } } }
named_scope :in_month, lambda { |date| { :conditions => ["? <= joining_date AND joining_date <= ?",
                                                          date.beginning_of_month, date.end_of_month]} }

Student.joined.in_month(@start_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Student.where(joined: true, 
  joined_date: @start_date.beginning_of_mont..@start_date.end_of_month)
```

You can accept a range in the hash condition! But not in SQL string condition...

If you want to use string condition which placeholders:

```
Student.where(':start_of_month <= joined_date AND joined_date <= :end_of_month',
                start_of_month: @start_date.beginning_of_month, 
                end_of_month: @start_date.end_of_month)
       .where(joined: true)
```

BY THE WAY, is the `join` attribute any useful? I mean if the joining_date is present, the the student `join` true, no?

Anyway, the best way is to move those dirty queries in a scope:

```
scope :joined, -> { where(join: true) }

scope :during_month, -> month { where(joined_date: month.beginning_of_month..month.end_of_month) }
```

Then, you can write `Student.joined.during_month`

**I just noticed it was for rails 2** sorry

Comment: Thanks @spikermann... It worked.. But if I am using named scope how do I retireve only selected records that is returned.. Because I am getting duplicate students records but with different dates.. So I need to display only unique student records details